# Retrieve Facebook's userID from PFFacebookUtils

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as backend service for my iOS app. One of the features I implemented is login via Facebook. In parse data explorer I can see, that parse stores facebook's userId if user logged in using his facebook account. I know that I can explicitly use FacebookSDK and use something like:

```
  [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:]
```

and than save userId in my custom field. But since parse had already done that for it's own purposes, I was wondering if there's a way I can retrieve that facebook's userId from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out PFUser class has private property `authData` with all necessary information. We can retrieve it like this:

```
PFUser* user = PFUser.currentUser;
NSDictionary* authData = [user valueForKey:@"authData"];
```

While it works in `Parse SDK v.1.9.1`, it may fail to work in upcoming or previous versions of SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as the authData from the Parse _User table is not returned to the client. You should to a regular FBSDKGraphRequest to "/me"